# URL Rewriting: Show all files of certain directories at root of site

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect

So I've got the following code which shows all the files of /guides at the root of my site. I would however also like to show all of the files of /news at the root of my site but I can't figure out how I could do both of these at the same time.

Like this:

```
example.com/guides/google --> example.com/google
example.com/news/youtube --> example.com/youtube
```

Simply duplicating the rewrite rule and changing it to /news throws a 403 and seems to mess everything up. Here's my current code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /guides/$1 [L]
```

Thank you and sorry for the novice question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/guides/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /guides/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/news/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /news/$1 [L]
```